# Remove curly braces from pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am using pandas dataframe. I want to remove the curly brackets from one column.

| column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {a, b, c, d} |
| 2 | {x, y, z} |

Need output is

| column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a, b, c, d |
| 2 | x, y, z |

Is there any way to remove those curly braces

Answer (score 1):

If values are sets use [`Series.str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html):

```
df['Column B'] = df['Column B'].str.join(', ')
```

If values are strings use [`Series.str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html):

```
df['Column B'] = df['Column B'].str.strip('{}')
```